# How to avoid many connected DEALER-s to crash a ZeroMQ ROUTER?

Tags: zeromq, distributed-computing, low-latency

I have a `ROUTER`-socket in an application that multiple `DEALER`-sockets, in different applications, connect to. I'd like the `ROUTER` to be as robust as possible.

Here is a specific scenario I'd like to handle well on the `ROUTER` :

1. 1000-s of `DEALER`-s connect to the `ROUTER`
2. Each `DEALER` sends a request to the `ROUTER` than will make the `ROUTER` send a large response back to the `DEALER`
3. Instead of reading the response, `DEALER`-s immediately repeat step two

A behavior I see on the `ROUTER` : it creates a ton of very large ZeroMQ messages for the responses, then does a zmq send back to the `DEALER`. ZeroMQ becomes responsible for deallocating the messages when they are actually sent. Since the `DEALER`-s never call `recv()`, ZeroMQ holds the message forever and the memory is slowly 'leaked' until the O/S kills the process when it runs out of memory.

Some options I've used that help :

`ZMQ_SNDHWM` : limits us to only holding N-messages in our outgoing queue to each `DEALER`, though not ideal because a `ROUTER` will drop outgoing messages when the queue is full

`ZMQ_SNDTIMEO` : ZeroMQ will discard message after N-milliseconds, without a successful send

With these options specified it's still possible to crash the `ROUTER` if 1000s of `DEALER` connections are opened, as the High Water Mark is applied on a per client basis.

Are there any other options I could use to protect against client requests crashing me?

Answer (score 0):

> **Q** : *"Are there any other options I could use to protect against client requests crashing me?"*

While the setup goes beyond my imagination, why to move zillions of bytes not to ever `.recv()` them, let me propose you one trick to throttle the memory-allocations to a working minimum :

We may use the `.setsockopt( zmq.CONFLATE )`-trick (using a Python dialect), not to buffer anything else more but a one, the most recent, incoming message.